# EXTJS: Scrolling of the page is very slow in windows XP

Tags: javascript, extjs, windows-xp, node-webkit

EXTJS: When I update data in XTemplate for every second in a tab panel, scrolling of the page became slow as data is continuously rendering into the template in windows XP

I have a tab panel with nearly 10 tabs. In each tab I am rendering data  every second into some tables which are created using XTemplates.

I am not facing any issue with windows 7 and 10.

Could anyone please provide your suggestions.

Please find the below panel:

```
Ext.define('View.components.TestDataPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    alias: 'widget.components-testDataPanel',

    requires: [],

    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            tpl: this.panelTemplate(),
            data: {}
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    panelTemplate: function () {        
        return new Ext.XTemplate('<div>'
            + '<h2>Test1</h2>'
            + '<table>'
            + '<tpl for="List">'
            + '<tr>'
            + '<td>{Content1}</td>'
            + '<td>{Content2}</td>'
            + '<td>{Content3}</td>'
            + '</tr>'
            + '</tpl>'
            + '</table>'
            + '</div>'

            + '<div>'
            + '<h2>Test2</h2>'
            + '<table>'
            + '<tr><th>Header1</th><th>Code</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th></tr>'
            + '<tpl for="List2">'
            + '<tr>'
            + '<td>{Content1}</td>'
            + '<td>{Content2}</td>'
            + '<td>{Content3}</td>'            
            + '</tr>'
            + '</tpl>'
            + '</table>'
            + '</div>',{
            disableFormats: true
        });
    }
});
```

In controller :

```
OnData : function (data) {
    var testPanel = this.getTestDataPanel();
    if(testPanel && data) {
       testPanel.update(data)
    }
}
```

In each tab in the tabpanel we have these type of panels and are updated with the data every second. 
The code is working fine and giving the expected results except the performance of scrollbar. Also switching between the tabs is very slow if the data is rendering continuously. Windows 7 and 10 is perfectly working as expected also no performance issues with them.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is the performance inconsistent using the same browser (e.g. Firefox 57) across the different systems?

Comment: It's a desktop application with Node webkit 0.14.7 and Extjs 5. I am facing this problem only in windows XP. In windows 7 and 10 application is working a expected.

Comment: Is it because of the DOM is getting modified every time? If so, is there any other solution?

Comment: You can look into how Sencha does it in their `datapicker` component. In short, they don't apply all the templates every time something changes, they only render the template once and change the values by directly accessing the DOM. I remember the comments said something about better performance.

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you so much. I am using renderTpl instead of tpl. But how to update the renderData dynamically on receiving data? Generally we can use cmp.update(data) but if I use update, the complete panel going invisible. Could you please suggest me what to do here?

Comment: I am new to Extjs. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I failed with using renderTpl. So i tried modified the code as below: 

Ext.applyIf(this, {
            tpl: this.panelTemplate()
        });

Will it update only the content now or it will update the DOM as well? Currently I am seeing DOM is getting updated. any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.